# Enable Button in Excel to click only if Active Cell is in Column A

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have a button in Excel which runs a macro that copies values from column A, what i am wanting is to only allow the button to be clicked if the active cell is in column A and have the button greyed out or disabled if the active cell is anywhere else?

Is this possible??

Comment: What language/api? Please [edit] and add a tag for that.

Comment: Apologies, this is for VBA in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do what I want. Incorporate an If statement with a call to the macro I want enabled.

This is my code

If ActiveCell. Column = 1 then 
Call 'whatever sub you want to run' 
Else
MsgBox ("Please select Column A") 
End If

End Sub